# How do i correctly add shared_pointers to probably derived classes into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, shared-ptr, object-slicing

I have basically this setup:

```
class B { /* ... */};
class C1 : public B { /* ... */};
class C2 : public B { /* ... */};

class X
{
  std::vector<shared_ptr<B>> m_vec;
  void addToVector(B* b);
}
```

`addToVector` cant know how many classes derive from B and should not care. It will be called like this:

```
someFunction() {
  C1 tmp;
  /* do something with tmp */
  m_myX.addToVector(&tmp);
}
```

so at the end of `someFunction`, tmp is getting out of scope and will be deleted. `addToVector` has to push_back a shared_ptr to a copy of tmp into the vector, but how can it do that?

```
void X::addToVector(B* b)
{
  int i = sizeof(b); // allways sizeof(B) :(
  shared_ptr<B> np(b);
  m_vec.push_back(np); // garbage collected after calling fn returns :(
}
```

What it should do is:

- make a copy of the object b is pointing to by calling the copy constructor/operator of the *correct* class
- push_back a shared_ptr to that copy into the vector.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an object on the stack and then giving its address to a `shared_ptr` which will try to  `delete` an object on the stack, which is undefined behaviour.

The solution is to stop doing that:

```
void someFunction() {
  C1* c = new C1;
  /* do something with *c */
  m_myX.addToVector(c);
}
```

Now you have an object on the heap, which can be owned by a `shared_ptr`. There's no need to make a copy of it.

This will only work correctly if `B` has a virtual destructor, but that can be avoided (and the code can be made safer and cleaner) by creating a shared_ptr in the first place:

```
void someFunction() {
  auto c = std::make_shared<C1>();
  /* do something with *c */
  m_myX.addToVector(c);
}

void X::addToVector(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
{
  m_vec.push_back(np);
}
```

Now the heap object is managed by `shared_ptr` as soon as it's created, and then safely stored in the vector.

Comment: Your 2nd approach has the disadvantage, that the client needs to know implementation details of `X` while the first has the disadvantage that a `new` without a corresponding `delete` looks a bit suspect. My intention was to provide something like `push_back` on `std::vector`s: it copies but you dont have to care for that.

Comment: So change the 2nd approach to use `unique_ptr` instead, that doesn't imply anything about the internals of `X`, it just allows the client to say "I am giving you ownership of this pointer". `X` can then do what it wants, e.g. store it in a `vector<shared_ptr<B>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<B>>` (which might be better anyway). However for that to work correctly you need a virtual destructor for `B` again.

Comment: As for having a `new` without a `delete`, there is a `delete`, it's just done automatically by the `shared_ptr`. That is better than your initial code, which has a `delete` without a `new`, which is very very bad indeed!

Answer (score 2):

your 'someFunction' looks strange... (why not create `tmp` as `shared_ptr` in the first place?)

to make it work you will have to create 'virtual constructor' - add virtual method `B* deepCopy() const` in B, and implement it in all subclasses, it's body should be based on pattern: `{ return new DerivedType(*this); }`

If you want to be clean - make `deepCopy` returning `shared_ptr` and using `make_shared`.

Comment: "add pure virtual method" that will make B an abstract class, he may not want that

Comment: @Othman Benchekroun - true, 'pure' is not needed here, removed

Comment: Or, to be flexible as well as clean, have `deepCopy` return `std::unique_ptr<B>`. This can be assigned to a `shared_ptr`, or kept unique - no need to force shared ownership on the client.

Comment: Same reason as in the comment on Jonathans answer: the client-side `shared_ptr-`approach has the disadvantage, that the client needs to know implementation details of `X`. My intention was to provide something like `push_back` on `std::vector`s: it copies but you dont have to care for that.